# bing maps: how to set zoom level so pinpoint is visible to users current location

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am using bing maps ajax v7 and for simplicity's sake let's say I have 10 PinPoints placed around the world.  I'm trying to have the map zoom to the lowest level so that the closest PinPoint is still visible to the current location of the user.  If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
            credentials: "myCredentials",
            backgroundColor: "#A4C4ED",
            zoom: 3,
            height: windowHeight,
            width: windowWidth
        });
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', hideInfoBox);
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', hideInfoBox);

        //get users location and set view bound
        var geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);
        var viewRectangle = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect(geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition());
        map.setView({ bounds: viewRectangle });

        dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(dataLayer);

        var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

        //create initial infobox
        infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), {
            visible: false,
            offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 20)
        });
        infoboxLayer.push(infobox);

        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', { callback: searchModuleLoaded });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you is one pin point and you have another 10 pin points located somewere on the map.

First you need to find the pinpoint that is closest to you. 
 You can use this function that expect two location objects that contains latitude and longitude.

```
oLocation1 = {latitude:0,longitude:0};
oLocation2 = {latitude:19,longitude:23};


 function calcDistHaversine  (oLocation1, oLocation2) {
        var dLat = (oLocation2.latitude * Math.PI / 180 - oLocation1.latitude  * Math.PI / 180);//*Math.PI*180;
        var dLon = (oLocation2.longitude * Math.PI / 180 - oLocation1.longitude  * Math.PI / 180);//*Math.PI*180;
        var lat1 = oLocation1.latitude * Math.PI / 180;//*Math.PI*180;
        var lat2 = oLocation2.latitude  * Math.PI / 180;//*Math.PI*180;

        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var distance = 6371 * c;
        return distance;
    };
```

As a result you will get the distance between those two location with respect yo earth curvature.

Now you have your location and closest pinpoint location.

Lets name them as your,their.

Next you need to create array that contains those two location converted to microsoft location objects.

```
  var yourLocation= new Microsoft.Maps.Location(your.latitude, your.longitude);
  var theirLocation= new Microsoft.Maps.Location(their.latitude, their.longitude);

  var arr = [];
  arr.push(yourLocation);
  arr.push(theirLocation);
```

Now you use bing maps feature that gives you best zoom and pointing according to given locations.

```
var bestView = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(arrLocations);
```

Then you set the map view according to the best view that we found.

```
 setTimeout((function () {
        map.setView({ bounds: bestView });
    }).bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: why is `setTimeout` function needed? I was using it without the timeout and the map wouldn't zoom. Added the timeout as explained here and works fine

Comment: All staff happens a sync, so 1 second is a rough buffer until all pins are actually drawed by map engine.
Only then you can make setView with bounds.

Comment: ok, but isn't there an event I can my put `setView` code so I don't have to wait? It seems to fragile

Comment: You right its fragile, but bing lack some very important events like map idle or map finished loading, the only set of events you can play with are "view change".
You can try to call "setView" after "view change end" triggered but i don't have time to test my suggestion.By the way if the answer with timeout is worked for you please accept it.

Comment: It did work for me but this is not my question :) I already upvoted it